# Different Intro based on day of the week - PHP

Tags: php, video, if-statement

I hope you guys can help me, as a beginner at php I've run up against a problem that I haven't been able to solve.

The Goal is a different Video-Intro based on the day of the week, including different Versions of the Video for each day.

Based on the following [Code](http://forum.hostek.com/showthread.php?404-Different-page-content-based-on-day-of-the-week-in-PHP) as you can see in the example of my code i added a video-intro inside of a div-tag.

The thing is, each day is supposed to have 4 different Videos.
Is it possible to change the video source, each time the website gets reloaded or some other way to do this.

```
<?
if( date( 'w' ) == 6 ) {
?>  
    <div class="intro_container">
        <a href="#content_start" class="skip_buttom">skip intro</a>

        <video id="intro_samstag" class="intro_video video-js vjs-default-skin" autoplay preload="auto" data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
            <source src="video_oma/mp4/samstag_01.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
            <source src="video_oma/webm/samstag_01.webm" type='video/webm' />
        </video>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var myPlayer = videojs("intro_samstag");
            videojs("intro_samstag").ready(function(){
                this.on("ended", function(){
                    $(".intro_container").css("display", "none");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
<?
}
?>
```

Comment: are you asking for http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Comment: Why not storing filepaths for videos in your database. and just echoing them accordingly. I mean you can randomize the video that should be displayed then.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `rand` element and generate the url for the video from that.

```
<?php

switch( date( 'w' ) ) {
    case 0:
        $vid_name = 'samstag_0'.rand(4);
        break;
    case 1:
        $vid_name = 'samstag_1'.rand(4);
        break;

    ...

}

?>

<div class="intro_container">
    <a href="#content_start" class="skip_buttom">skip intro</a>

    <video id="intro_samstag" class="intro_video video-js vjs-default-skin" autoplay preload="auto" data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
        <source src="video_oma/mp4/<?=$vid_name?>.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
        <source src="video_oma/webm/<?=$vid_name?>.webm" type='video/webm' />
    </video>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myPlayer = videojs("intro_samstag");
        videojs("intro_samstag").ready(function(){
            this.on("ended", function(){
                $(".intro_container").css("display", "none");
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```